# How do I Transport SAP Standard Texts?

Tags: sapscript

SAP Standard text is not automatically added to a transport request.  What do I have to do to add it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are unfamiliar with how to add objects to a transport manually, or do not have authorisation to do so:

1. Execute the report RSTXTRAN
2. Fill in the appropriate fields. *Note* "Name of correction" has to be the transport *task* number, not the request number
3. Execute
4. Select the Objects that you want to add and press ENTER
5. Click on "Transfer texts to corr."

The text object should now be visible in your transport request via SE10

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with how to add objects to a transport request manually:

- Create a Workbench request with Transport Task of type Development/Correction
- Add the Text object manually:

  Program ID:  R3TR
   Object Type: TEXT
   Object Name: TEXT,*TEXT_NAME*,ST,E